# Boundedness of $\int_0^t e^{-(t-\tau)}x(\tau) d\tau$

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to bound the following function $y$.

Given a differentiable and monotone decreasing function $x(\tau)$, define $y$ as follows:

$$y(t)= \int_0^t e^{-(t-\tau)} x(\tau) d\tau.$$

While searching about the function, there is no result about boundedness of that function.

Does anybody know?

Comment: Take the differentiable and monotonically decreasing $x(\tau ) = \mathrm{e}^{ - \tau /2} $. Then for $t\ge 0$, $$
y(t) = \frac{2}{3}\mathrm{e}^t  - \frac{2}{3}\mathrm{e}^{ - t/2}  \ge \frac{2}{3}(\mathrm{e}^t  - 1)
$$ is unbounded.

Comment: Why the `exponential-sum` tag? Did you read its description?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong formula and corrected it.

Comment: I guess there should be a plus sign in brackets?

Comment: On what domain $x(\tau)$ is assumed to be differentiable? The domain $\tau>0$ is not enough (take $x(\tau)=1/\tau$). If it is continuous for $\tau\ge 0$ and bounded, $|x(\tau)|\leq K$, then $$
\left| {y(t)} \right| \le \int_0^t {{\rm e}^{ - (t - \tau )} \left| {x(\tau )} \right|{\rm d}\tau }  \le K\int_0^t {{\rm e}^{ - (t - \tau )} {\rm d}\tau }  = K(1 - {\rm e}^{ - t} ) \le K
$$ for any $t\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Why should the function be bounded? If $x(\tau) = 1,$ then $y(t) = e^t(1-e^{-t}) = e^t - 1,$ which does not seem very bounded.